# What is the difference between these Canon full frame cameras?

Tags: canon, full-frame

I am about to buy a Canon full frame camera. I wonder which one to buy. Is there any visible different between the photos from these cameras:

- Canon 6D Mark II
- Canon 5D Mark III
- Canon 5D Mark IV

I take photos for families, portraits and small wedding parties.

Answer (score 11):

Without wanting to seem too harsh: if you don't understand the differences between those cameras, you're probably not ready to buy one.

More generally, if you put similar format cameras if you put them on a tripod and take measure the results very carefully, you can tell the difference between the photos; this is exactly what [DxOMark](https://www.dxomark.com/) do - but in the vast majority of circumstances, that's probably not what you care about. You care about the ergonomics, you care about the autofocus system, you care about the viewfinder, you care about the frames per second, you (might) care about the video features (only the 5D Mark IV does 4K), you care about having two memory cards, etc, etc. All those things are probably much more important than the minor differences between the quality of the images you get under ideal circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any visible difference between the photos from these cameras

That all depends on where each of them is pointed and who is pointing them.

If they're all using the same lens, taking photos of the same scene, and being used by the same photographer then most of the differences will come down to:

- The skill level of the photographer with regard to the particular kind of image being attempted. How much help does the photographer need from the camera for this particular kind of shot? How much does this shot demand the photographer understand the scene better than the camera does?
- The knowledge the photographer has of each camera's systems and how the differences between those systems affect the desired outcome of the image. It may well be that one camera would be slightly better for getting some shots, while another camera would be slightly better for other shots the photographer desires.
- The experience level of the photographer taking similar types of images with each of the cameras in question. There's no substitute for experience when to comes to choosing which tool is the most appropriate for a specific job. Experience with each tool and experience with each type of job will contribute to the ability to choose the right tool for a specific job.
- The judgement of the photographer to appropriately choose which camera is most capable of performing best in a particular role. There's no such thing as "the best camera." There's only (sometimes) "the best camera for taking this particular image."

If the photographer is more familiar with the subtleties of operation of even the least capable of the three cameras, it is quite possible the best results *for that specific photographer* may come from using that least capable camera with which the photographer is most experienced, knowledgeable, and comfortable using.

As the old saying often attributed to Mark Twain goes: *Good judgement is the result of experience and experience is the result of bad judgement.*

If you don't have the experience needed to properly judge the subtleties of the differences between these three cameras, for you there is no real difference between them.